# Белое и красное мясо повышают?

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число

> Учёные: белое и красное мясо повышают уровень холестерина одинаково.

Наличие слова *одинаково* оправдывает мн. ч. глагола?

https://russian.rt.com/science/news/637903-uchyonye-myaso-holesterin

Answer (score 2):

В этой теме (согласование существительных со сказуемым) важно рассматривать **конкретное** предложение.

Да, мы знаем, что мясо — это неисчисляемое существительное и употребляется только в единственном числе, но эта информация сейчас не на первом плане, она для нас не является  значимой.

Нам важно, чтобы предложение было согласовано "на слух".

А здесь всё в порядке. Союз И подразумевает два предмета (мн. число), и этого вполне достаточно, чтобы мы "благосклонно"  воспринимали этот вариант.

А вот единственное число не будет понятным, а другого варианта нет.

Answer (score 1):

Дело вовсе не в слове "одинаково". Здесь оно просто выполняет роль обстоятельства образа действия, но относится, кстати говоря, к обоим видам мяса.

Множественное число в данном случае вполне уместно. Как я понял, Вас смутило то, что слово "мясо" употреблено в единственном числе (отмечу, что оно может быть употреблено только в этом числе), а глагол -- во множественном. Я не так давно разбирал данный вопрос для себя и пришёл к следующему выводу:

*Два и более определения при **собирательном** понятии обозначают его разные виды, являющиеся отдельными объектами*.

Для пояснения приведу два примера и сравню их:

"Добрые и злые **люди** шли по дороге". Здесь "люди" -- множественное число слова "человек". Глагол употреблён верно и описывает, что по дороги шли **хорошие люди** и **плохие люди**".

"**Белое** и **красное** мясо повышают уровень холестерина одинаково". В этом же случае мы имеем дело с **неисчисляемым существительным**. Однако, как мы видим, у него есть **два** определения, причём они таковы, что **не могут одновременно относиться к одному и тому же понятию**. Отсюда можно сделать вывод, что понятия **должны быть разными**, следовательно мы имеем дело с **несколькими объектами**, поэтому глагол употребляется во **множественном** числе.
Надеюсь, помог разобраться, почему глаголы употреблён во множественном числе.

Answer (score 1):

Для *множественного* числа глагола достаточно присутствия *двух* разных сущностей (белое и красное мясо = белое мясо и красное мясо - дело не в окончании), а вот *единственное* число требует обоснования: в ряде случаев можно мысленно представить себе одно и другое *поочерёдно* (условно говоря, *белое мясо, как и красное...*). Добавленное же слово делает здесь множественное число *единственно возможным* по смысловым причинам (как и выражение "в равной мере"), поскольку "*одинаковость*" требует сопоставления двух *одновременно присутствующих* сущностей.